# Python text file

Tags: python

I have a txt file which is approx 25 columns wide and 5 columns deep, I have written the following script

```
for line in open("ABC.txt"):
    fg = line.split("\t")
    minimum = fg[17]
    print minimum
```

This is finding column 18 data which is

```
Supplier B
567
4444
2.77
19
```

Questions is: how can I get just the data for `4444`?

Jezza

Comment: By using split() again on 'fg' ?

Comment: What criterion are you using to choose `4444`? Because it's the third value in that column?

Comment: Your specs are extremely vague, so it's really hard to provide a working answer for you. Please copy and paste a relevant sample of the file you're working on (at least all the rows until the one that you're interested it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python already has everything built-in you need for this: the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
with open("ABC.txt", "rb") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="\t")
    data = list(reader)
minimum = data[2][17]
```

Now `minimum` will contain `4444` if that's the 18th value in the 3rd row.

Comment: Hey tim the only issue I have now is that 4444 seems like a text, how do I get it so I can use the actual number so if the result is 4444 and I wanted to add 6 it would be 4450

Comment: @GreggyD: `minimum = int(data[2][17])`

Comment: For the column I actually need I get this error now: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '8633.3112'

Comment: @GreggyD use `float()` instead of `int()`.

Comment: Thanks Ashwini that got it, now will get on with the rest of it. Appreciate all those that provided comments

Answer (score 1):

try something like, `split()` at `'\n'`:

```
In [89]: minimum="""Supplier B
567
4444
2.77
19"""
In [90]: minimum.split('\n')
Out[90]: ['Supplier B', '567', '4444', '2.77', '19']

In [91]: minimum.split('\n')[2]
Out[91]: '4444'
```

Comment: It appears that due to a formatting error, the question was incorrectly displayed, so your answer fixes the wrong problem...

Comment: I have changed the code to the following and I get a list index out of range error                                                      for line in open("ABC.txt"):
    fg = line.split("\t")
    minimum = fg[17]
    dg = minimum.split('\n')[2]
    print dg

Comment: I think you're still misreading the question. Column 18 in row 1 is `"Supplier B"`, column 18 in row 2 is `"567"`, etc.

Comment: OK either 567 or 4444 I am just trying to extract 1 of the number in that column, I have tried the example above and I get a error

Comment: Ashwini the error is: list index out of range. Sorry but fairly new to this apologies if I am not detailing it correctly

Comment: @GreggyD Try printing your list first to see how many elements that list  contains.

Comment: I actually get 8 in the list as the first 3 lines are actually blank, because of this I have tried in the split of the column putting [7] in and it still gives the same error